# How to use seconds to schedule a task in Real Time For the Masses instead of cycles?

Tags: rust, real-time

I can only see examples using cycles of clock to schedule tasks in Real Time for the Masses (RTFM):

```
#[init(schedule = [foo])]
fn init() {
    schedule.foo(Instant::now() + PERIOD.cycles()).unwrap();
}
```

I can't find a variable containing the clock speed, the source code of RTFM is mostly syntax tree manipulation inaccessible to a beginner, I struggle to find uses of this API on GitHub. How do I relate cycles to seconds?

Comment: I fear that this is harder than one might think, because what `rtfm` provides with [`Instant`](https://japaric.github.io/cortex-m-rtfm/api/rtfm/struct.Instant.html) and [`Duration`](https://japaric.github.io/cortex-m-rtfm/api/rtfm/struct.Duration.html) is only an opaque monotonically nondecreasing clock, without a trivial translation to real-world time.

Comment: Do you know your processor's clock speed? Depending on how complex the processor is, the problem might be as simple as some division.

Answer (score 0):

I found something:

```
fn hertz_to_cycles(sysclock: Hertz, hertz: Hertz) -> Duration {
    return (sysclock.0 / hertz.0).cycles();
}

#[init(schedule = [toggle])]
unsafe fn init() {
    let mut rcc = device.RCC.constrain();
    let mut flash = device.FLASH.constrain();
    let clocks = rcc.cfgr.freeze(&mut flash.acr);
    let sysclock = clocks.sysclk();
    let period = hertz_to_cycles(sysclock, 2.hz());
    schedule.toggle(Instant::now() + period).unwrap();
}
```

I hope it gets the ball rolling for a serious answer.

Basically the scheduler is based on DWT (data watchpoint trigger), and that thing *has* to be clocked at the core speed, so I went to get it there.

Comment: Idiomatic Rust would just be `(sysclock.0 / hertz.0).cycles()` — no `return`, no `;`

Comment: *for a serious answer* — why do you believe this isn't a serious answer? Seems reasonable, assuming that your processor architecture always runs one operation per clock cycle.

Comment: My extensive 2 days career in embedded rust tells me that they like to have a continuous connection by the static types between the moving parts of the system. here there is absolutely no explicit connection. In particular, there is no reason why the task scheduling system would have the same clock as the core, it's an implementation detail. Thanks for the syntax.